# $X$ is a random variable with finite variance. Let $Y=\alpha X + \beta$. Compute $E[(Y-E[Y|X])^2]$.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, variance

$X$ is a random variable with finite variance. Let $Y=\alpha X + \beta$. I've been asked to compute $E[(Y-E[Y|X])^2]$. Where do I start with this? Is the iterated conditional expectation formula relevant at all? Is this the expression for the conditional variance, and if so how is the useful to the computation?

Any guidance on what formulas to use would be great (so far I've only been taught about discrete & continuous random variables, expectation, variance, joint and marginal distributions and conditional distributions).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, we have that $E[Y\mid X]=Y$
(provided that $Y$ is integrable). Therefore, $Y-E[Y\mid X]=0$ and
hence $E\left[(Y-E[Y\mid X])^2\right]=0$.

Comment: I haven't got a background in measure theory, would you be able to explain this in a different way please?

Comment: Its not really about measure theory, per se.  It is just that because $Y$ is a function of $X$, you know what to expect $Y$ will be when you know what $X$ is.$$\begin{align}\Bbb E(Y\mid X)&=\Bbb E(\alpha X+\beta\mid X)\\&=\alpha X+\beta\\&=Y\end{align}$$

Comment: The point here, in words, is that the value of $Y$ is completely determined by the value of $X$.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Comment: How would I compute the same quantity but instead where: $Y=AX$, A has a (uniform) distribution & X and A are independent. Here, Y is not completely determined by X so I cannot use the same method. (If you could provide a hint and then hide the answer that would be great, as I want to give this a proper go). Thanks!

Comment: If $A$ and $X$ are independent then $$\begin{align}\Bbb E(AX\mid X) &= \Bbb E(A\mid X)~X \\ &= \Bbb E(A)~X\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi, $A$ has distribution $U(-1,1)$ and I got a final answer of $\frac{2}{9}E[X^2]$. Is this correct? Also, is it correct to write E(AX | X) = E(A|X)E(X|X) = E(A)X or not? And is the quantity I've been asked to compute equal to the conditional variance Var(Y|X)?